# Definition of a baneling bust

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

I heard day9 mention a baneling bust. What is a baneling bust?

Answer (score 14):

A "Baneling bust" is when you use a lot of Banelings to breach the enemy's "front door" - the bunch of buildings used at the ramp of the main base to block or hinder the enemy from entering.

Since Banelings do so much damage against buildings, they are very useful for quickly bringing down low-HP buildings commonly used for fortifying this front door - mainly supply depots, bunkers and pylons - and thus opening the way to the opponent's base. This tactic is called the Baneling bust, even if you destroy just some of the buildings composing that "door", not all of them.

The Baneling bust is a lot less useful against front doors made from higher-HP buildings, like gateways or barracks.

Comment: I'd like to add a baneling bust doesn't always have to target the front door of your enemy. I'd still consider an attack with banelings that destroys a bunker full of marines placed just outside of your main base (intended to prevent/harass a hatchery at your natural expansion) a baneling bust.

Comment: I'd say no to @Crag it's only referring to destroying a wall, not random structures.

Comment: I'd hardly consider a bunker positioned directly outside your base keeping you from expanding 'random'. I think busting out of your opponent's contain on your base using banelings would count as a baneling bust, but I guess others don't agree. I'll still use the term to describe that action though.